# Display nested list over hovering at parent list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu structure in which sub menus are present as nested lists like this

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="itm">A
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two
            <ul>
                <li>Menu Item</li>
                <li> Menu Item </li>
                <li> Menu Item </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> Three </li>
        <li> Four </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="icon"><span class="img"></span></li>
<li class="itm">B</li>
<li class="itm">C</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Nowi want to show the sub menu (sub list) when the cursor hovers over the parent `li` and for that I am doing this:

```
$('nav ul li').hover(function () {
    console.log(this);
    $(this > ul).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this > ul).fadeOut();
});
```

But on hover it showing this error in JS Console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ul is not defined`

Comment: Any particular reason you dont use CSS for that instead of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is combining `this`, which is a literal, and what should be a string in a selector (`> ul`). `ul` is being treated as a variable, and the `ul` variable doesn't exist.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyzsw/

```
$(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
```